# Flutter create a splash screen with text and loader

Tags: flutter, dart

I came to ask for help because I want to do a native splash screen type in my flutter application. So I want that when I launch my application, I have a page with the logo of my application, a descriptive text, the version number of the application and a loader.

After a lot of research I cannot find satisfactory tutorials. Either there are native splash screens that change the base color when the app is launched and we can just display a logo. Either we create a fake splash screen which is a start page but which is launched after the native start. I don't know if I'm clear ... Voila, but how can we all do it at the same time?